# Confusion with jquery selector implement to more than one element

Tags: jquery

I have particular function for auto complete list. Though its work great with page having single text box. I want to implement it on page having more than one text box. Suppose I have 10 text boxes and I want to implement it to all. I am bit confused with selector and all.

```
<input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" id="track_1"/>
      <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"><img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>


<input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" id="track_2"/>
      <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"><img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
```

My text boxes having such flow with different id's...
My jquery function is...

```
function lookup(poetname) { 
    if(poetname.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        //alert("Hiiii");
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+poetname+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#poetname').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** You should not use an ID for more than one element, use classes instead. ID's should be unique.

You could just bind the function to each input

```
$(function(){
  $("input.track").keyup(function(e){
    var poetname = $(this).val()
    if(poetname.length == 0){
      // Hide the suggestion box
      $(this).find('div.suggestionsBox').hide()
    }
    //...rest of code...//

  })
})
```

Comment: Can you please write more code. I am new with this still confused with this.

Comment: The best place to learn is from the [JQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works). Try something, if you get an error, ask another question! However, the problem with your solution was multiple elements having the same ID

Comment: actually I want you to rewrite my jquery code... else I try it myself.